# Formatting a phone number using substr

Tags: php, smarty

I would like to format a phone number differently depending whether it is a mobile number or a landline/ house phone. Mobile numbers in Australia start with 04; Can I do something like this :

```
{if (substr($number, 0,2) == '04'}

apply this format #### ### ###

{else}

apply this format (##) #### #### or #### ###
```

Depending if the area code was input.

I applied this to a template/html page and I have some problems.... The mobile numbers get recognized and formatted fine but the other numbers dont work.... This is what I did

```
{if $listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:0:2== '04'}
{$listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:0:4} 
{$listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:4:3} 
{$listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:7}

{elseif $listing.user[$v.caption]|strlen>8}
({$listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:0:2}) 
{$listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:2:4} 
{$listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:6}

{else}
{$listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:0:4} 
{$listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:4:4}
{/if}
```

Comment: You already have the code: that `if` statement you have will do it.

Comment: Is this just psuedocode, or is it Smarty template code? Also, you have an extra `(` before `substr()` if it's code you're actually using.

Comment: oh so thats the correct code aswel? lol cos i just had a guess based on how i read substr works...

Comment: @DanielLuca Documentation usually gives a pretty good idea of how something works :)

Comment: Which template engine? Smarty, Flexy, other?

Comment: thanks for you quick reply.... yeah i was reading documentation for few hours, but i couldent find anything similar to what i want where certain values/numbers could be identified in order for me to do what i need... ill give this a go and if i get stuck ill post what i did.

thanks

Comment: also how would i apply a format using substr

is this right?  $number.substr (0,4) $number.substr (4,3) $number.substr (7,3) to give this format #### ### ###

or is ther a method to do it all in one go?

Comment: Don't have time for a real answer, but here's something that can help. Here's an example of how to generate the first pattern. Just modify it to match your other versions: `echo preg_replace('/(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{3})/','\1 \2 \3',$number)`. This regular expression matches 3 groups of numbers (a group is what's in each paranthesis) The numbers between brackets represent the number of digits you want to catch in each group, and \1 refers to the first group, \2 the second etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement should do the trick:

```
//if the first two digits are `04` then use the format: #### ### ###
if (substr($number, 0, 2) == '04') {
    $number = substr($number, 0, 4) . ' ' . substr($number, 4, 3) . ' ' . substr($number, 7);

//otherwise do more checks on the number
} else {

    //if the number is longer than seven digits then use the format: (##) #### ####
    if (strlen($number) > 7) {
        $number = '(' + substr($number, 0, 2) . ') ' . substr($number, 2, 4) . ' ' . substr($number, 6);

    //otherwise use the format: #### ###
    } else {
        $number = substr($number, 0, 4) . ' ' . substr($number, 4, 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: i applied this to a template/html page the mobile numbers work fine but the other numbers dont work. have i done something wrong with my if statements?

{if $listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:0:2== '04'}
{$listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:0:4} 
{$listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:4:3} 
{$listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:7}
{elseif $listing.user[$v.caption]|strlen>8}
({$listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:0:2}) 
{$listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:2:4} 
{$listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:6}
{else}
{$listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:0:4} 
{$listing.user[$v.caption]|substr:4:4}
{/if}